# JNA - How to use FOREIGN_THREAD_START_ROUTINE class?

Tags: java, jna

It seems like the `FOREIGN_THREAD_START_ROUTINE` class (which appears to be the **JNA** representation for the `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE` class in **C**) may be broken and/or not a full implementation of the class. In no way as-is have I found it to be functional or even successfully created an instance of it.

The **Kernel32** function `CreateRemoteThread` requires it as a parameter, however I've found no way of actually creating an instance of it and any makeshift, identical classes of it which I've made have thrown an "**invalid memory access**" exception. When creating a new instance of it, it always throws an Exception with the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Structure.getFieldOrder() on class com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase$FOREIGN_THREAD_START_ROUTINE returns names ([foreignLocation]) which do not match declared field names ([])
```

But it also has **ONLY** a no-arg constructor and is not declared abstract, so having to override the `getFieldOrder` method AND re-declare the `foreignLocation` member (It is already declared in the class, but it's declared private and `getFieldOrder` is not overridden in the class itself so the `foreignLocation` member is therefore unavailable to the `getFieldOrder` method declared in the `Structure` class) in the instance itself seems like bad design to me.

**In short:**

is the `FOREIGN_THREAD_START_ROUTINE` class actually functional, and if it is, how can it be instantiated successfully?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may want to see (and comment on and help fix) https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/issues/1115